# Calling a JSON API

Tags: python, json, api

> The program will prompt for a location, contact a web service and retrieve JSON for the web service and parse that data, and retrieve the first place_id from the JSON. A place ID is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place as within Google Maps.
>
> #### API End Points
>
> To complete this assignment, you should use this API endpoint that has a static subset of the Google Data:
>
> http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson
>
> This API uses the same parameters (sensor and address) as the Google API. This API also has no rate limit so you can test as often as you like. If you visit the URL with no parameters, you get a list of all of the address values which can be used with this API.

```
import urllib
import json

serviceurl = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson'

while True:
    address = raw_input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1 : break

    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address':  address})
    print 'Retrieving', url
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'

    js = json.loads(str(data))
```

I am confused where is the place_id? All I can see is a list with many universities' names. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: No idea what you are asking

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: they didn't get the expected results (not a JSON object with a `place_id` key in it). That's because they called the service incorrectly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I understand that but it tells them exactly what to do in the question.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: so what's lacking here is figuring out what went wrong..

Comment: @MartijnPieters, or maybe a trip to specsavers..

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: we'll talk again when you try a new programming language or paradigm and miss something that someone experienced in the tools / language / etc. thinks obvious.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, here are clear instructions in the homework so unless the english language is what is new then I don't see how how your argument is relevant, you also start your answer with *Read your assignment:* which suggests that is also your view

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I few weeks back I coded my first PHP / Hack code. I made a simple mistake, *even though I read about that specific situation*. What happens is that there is *so much information* that you can't recall all of it at the right time. Making mistakes like these and having them point out by someone that spots it in a few seconds helps you never forget about the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your assignment:

> If you visit the URL with no parameters, **you get a list of all of the address values which can be used with this API.**

The service thinks you didn't pass in parameters, and that's because you didn't form your URL properly:

```
url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address':  address})
```

You need a `?` questionmark to separate the URL path from the query string; *with* the question mark the URL returns a full JSON object with `results` key:

```
url = serviceurl + '?' + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address':  address})
```

The resulting JSON object looks a little like this:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
             # component dictionaries
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Virginia Tech Trail, Virginia Beach, VA 23455, USA",
         "geometry" : {
             # geometry dictionary
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJw0P35CuUuokROoH5mxE5Pyg",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

So the `results` key is a list, holding dictionaries. Each such a dictionary has a `'place_id'` key.